# Dynamic Javascript Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Does anybody know how to convert my data to table by using Javascript or JQuery, I got this data for example:

```
var data1 = ["1","3","5"]
var data2 = ["a","b","c"]
```

- Once the data1 and data2 value is updated then the rows and columns are also automatic updated.

result:

etc:

No.  Alphabet
1      a
3      b
5      c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .html file

```
<table class="myTable"></table>
```

In your .js file

```
function generateTable(data1, data2){
  var $table = $('.myTable');
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
      var $aSingleContent = '<tr><td>'+data1[i]+'</td><td>'+data2[i]+'</td></tr>';
      $table.append($aSingleContent);
    }
}
function modifyData() {
  var data1 = ["1","3","5"];
  var data2 = ["a","b","c"];
  generateTable(data1, data2);
}
```

--------------------------------Update-------
I put the code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ronansmith/daLf9t85/

remember to add **External Resources** of jQuery
[image: add jQuery link in Fiddle]

Comment: Nothing display, Am I miss something? Can you kindly do check on this jsfiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/8kqrrbt1/

Comment: @azimhamdan  I updated it. Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/ronansmith/daLf9t85/ Because It's using jQuery, remember add the link. like the pic I put on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of creating a function to dynamically set the `innerHTML` of a `div`, propagating it with a table.

It should look something like this:

```
function generate_table(array1, array2) {

    var html = '<table>';

    // cycles through all the elements in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + array1[i] + '</td><td>' + array2[i] + '</td></tr>';
    }

    html += '</table>';

    // places the table in the element
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html; 

}
```

`generate_table()` takes in the two arrays and constructs a `String`, propagating it with the contents of the array in a for loop. Then it gets a `div` named `content` and sets its `innerHTML` to create the table.

In your webpage, be sure to include the `div` to which the table will be inserted:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

You can also call `generate_table()` every time your array refreshes, and the table will update.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Then where should I put the data1 and data2? sorry I'm new in Javascript programming

Comment: These are the parameters for the function. Call this method by placing `generate_table(data1, data2);` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can do this. one, you wrap a function/class around your data and have a "changedata" method that changes the data and updates the html or you have a setInterval that listens for changes to those variables and serves the changes to you markup. the former is much better than the latter in my opinion

Comment: Can you do the example of the table i meant the code because I need the code for explanation, Thanks